# How can I correct the boundaries after image segmentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, image-processing

I used graph-cut algorithm for image segmentation and results are not proper. Need to improve the boundaries with proper polygon and line in segmented image.

[image: Segmented image]

```
segments = felzenszwalb(img, scale=k, sigma=sigma, min_size=minsize)

toCheckImg = np.zeros_like(img)
toCheckImg = find_boundaries(segments,connectivity=segments.ndim).astype(np.uint8)

image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(toCheckImg,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: whats not proper? whats a proper polygon? elaborate

Answer (score 0):

1/ you can use an edge detector and then interpolate the remaining values in your image for getting the boundaries. 
2/ to correct the boundaries you can apply a gaussian filter with a very low sigma so that the boundaries are extracted out. 
Please let me know if you face any problem .